# Android custom linear layout manager returns 0 item count after updating support libraries to 23.3.0

Tags: android, android-navigationview, linearlayoutmanager

After updating the android design and support libraries to 23.3.0, the custom linear layout manager is throwing this exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid item position 0(0). Item count:0
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4622)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
at com.gibbr.utility.MyLinearLayoutManager.onMeasure(MyLinearLayoutManager.java:29)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2614)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Getting error in this line:

```
View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
```

This is the code for `RecyclerView` on which I am binding this layout manager:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/handle_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Earlier with the support library version 23.1.0, it was working fine but after updating this is throwing error. Also I need to update it to 23.3.0 as I am not able to add `NavigationView` in the 23.1.0 design library. 
It throws following error in xml file:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.NavigationView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater
```

and the following **error** on the runtime:

```
05-30 12:40:08.633 17955-17955/com.main E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.main, PID: 17955
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.main/com.main.mainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
at com.main.mainActivity.onCreate(mainActivity.java:102)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
at com.main.mainActivity.onCreate(mainActivity.java:102) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:82)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
at com.main.mainActivity.onCreate(mainActivity.java:102) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Please guide me how to fix this!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a recycler view updating support libraries from 23.1.1 to 25.0.1. In my case I had to remove a custom LinearLayoutManager extention class (called *WrappingLinearLayoutManager*) and just used a LinearLayoutManager.

changed

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new WrappingLinearLayoutManager(ctx));
```

to

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ctx));
```

I hope this may help you.